# The content of my user inputted array isn't what was entered

Tags: java, arrays

I have a ten spot array in my code, which is user inputted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraya.length; i++){
     arraya[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

After entering

`2, 4, 53, 2, 3, 46, 45, 5, 4, 3`

the array that was printed read

`[I@86b012`

How do I fix this?

Comment: where is the code of printing array?

Answer (score 2):

You might be printing array like

[`System.out.print(arraya);`](http://ideone.com/qbo46u) which internally calls `arraya.toString()`  and gives `[I@86b012` .

- `[I` - is a class name
- `[` - an single-dimensional array
- `@` -  joins the string together
- `86b012` - the hashcode of the object

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/3841803)

you have to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraya.length; i++){
     System.out.print(arraya[i]+" ");
}
```

or

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arraya));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/aOGtvx)

Comment: Or `System.out.println( Arrays.toString(arraya) );`.

Comment: Arrays cannot be resolved?

Comment: @GDaniels if you are second method in my answer dont forget to `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Apparently "The import import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved"

Comment: I'm not sure what this is for, but I'm using DrJava, and there's no BuildPath under project.

Comment: @GDaniels  use the first method of printing array as given in my answer

Comment: Doesn't that only work inside of the for loop? I want to print it later.

Comment: @GDaniels check the [demo](http://ideone.com/aOGtvx)

Comment: Like I said, java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @GDaniels I have given you the demo with both methods with `seperate loop` and with `Arrays` you can use any one so if second method dint work use the first methods.

Answer (score 0):

Every java object has a toString() method, and the default method is to display the object's class name representation, then "@" followed by its hashcode. What you're seeing is the default toString() representation of an int array. To print the actual data in the array, you can:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arraya));
```

Or you can loop through the array like other's have suggested